# JavaFX Bind SimpleBooleanProperty to multiple properties

Tags: java, javafx, binding

I'm working on a simple Java program to do some simple mySQL stuff. It has a little GUI made with JavaFX.

The GUI's controller has got a SimpleBooleanProperty, let's call it X, which indicates the connection status to the database.
I've bound simple things to it, like the disableProperty of a button so send queries, which should be disabled if there is no connection. So far so good.

I have a label which is meant to do the following:

- if X is true:  text = connected, background = 'green'
- if X is false: text = disconnected, background = 'red'

I plan to achieve this by binding X in any way to multiple properties of the label, but I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: As far as I can tell, you don't want to bind a single boolean property to multiple properties but rather you want to bind multiple properties to a single boolean property. There is no limit to how many properties can bind to a single property. As for conditional bindings take a look at [`Bindings#when(ObservableBooleanValue)`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.base/javafx/beans/binding/Bindings.html#when(javafx.beans.value.ObservableBooleanValue)). Note that another approach is to use `PseudoClass` and CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Bindings.when() was exactly was I was looking for, thanks a lot!